# Page title not displayed at the top of the Content area

Tags: 7

The page title is displayed in the breadcrumb, but not as a page title, at the top of the content area. Is there a setting somewhere I can edit, or will I need to manually add it to node.tpl.php?

The Title field is there, in the Content type - manage fields.

The search results page however, does have the page title displayed at the top of the content...(?)

Comment: This is often affected by your theme.  Are you using a contrib theme or one you built yourself?  If a contrib theme, which one?

Comment: I am using the Bartik theme...

Comment: Did you tweak the Bartik theme? In node.tpl.php, `if !$page`, there is `print $title`.

Comment: @kine456, do you mean node title or page title?

Comment: I have made changes to the css but not the node.tpl.php file. I have the following:
  <?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
      <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
    </h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

Comment: Page title. But I thought that node = page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your `node.tpl.php`, if the node is viewed in teaser mode, that `$title` variable will be output. (`if (!$page):`)

For the node view in full page mode (`if ($page == TRUE):`) then you need to have `print $title` in your theme `page.tpl.php`

i.e:

```
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if ($title): ?>
    <h1 class="title" id="page-title">
      <?php print $title; ?>
    </h1>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```